# Track file download from sql database

Tags: android, sql, json, android-sqlite

I am developing an appstore application for andriod.

I want to sort items according to the count they have been downloaded. Android application uses Json for getting the information of the files and files information is located in a sql database.

How can I query the count of downloads for each file so that I can sort them by the number of downloads?

Answer (score 0):

Add an ORDER BY clause to your SQL query

something like `ORDER BY COUNT(Downloads) DESC`

Comment: is `Downloads` determined in sql? I mean will rows be sorted by the number of being downloaded automatically?

Comment: What is the query you are currently using to the get the downlaod count. Please post it and I can show you how to update it.

Comment: I don't use any query for getting download count. Cause I don't know this query.